# Compare date by day length - JAVA

Tags: java, date

i want to ask you, if you help me with this problem...

I have two date:

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31"); 
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-31");
```

I want to compare a date, whether the difference in them X days

```
        int x = 30; // I need to delete the file if it is older than 30 days

        if(isOldThan30days(date1,date2, x)){
           //delete file
        }else{
           //nothing
        }
```

I hope you understand me :-). How can i do this? Thank you.

Comment: Java 8 `Period betweenDates = Period.between(startDate, endDate); int diffMonths = betweenDates.getMonths()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try like this to get the days between two dates:

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays();
```

Then you can do this:

```
if(days > 30)
{
  //delete files
}
else
{
  //whatever
}
```

Comment: What java imports i need for use 'DAYS' ?

Comment: @user3784463:- http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Calendar` for that issue:

```
    Calendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    c1.setTime(date1);

    Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    c2.setTime(new Date());

    c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

    if (c2.after(c1)){
        //delete Fiels
    }
```

Comment: But, in your code : c1=c2 ?

Comment: @user3784463 sorry my fault, have changed my answer.